# Why did I get a bios failure unannounced?

Tags: bios, acer-aspire

Acer aspire one (windows XP) failed to boot. Found instructions for flashing the bios
Did so and it worked. All is now well.
Question: why did it fail? Was it something I might have done? If so what.Will it do it again unannounced? Last normal use of computer was normal with  normal closure

Comment: How did you flash the BIOS if the system failed to boot?

Comment: Please explain the condition of the machine before flashing the bios in more detail. How was it failing to boot? Before flashing did you try just clearing or resetting the bios?

Answer (score 1):

If it happens again, better check the cmos/bios battery.
If it's weakening, that could explain losing the bios.

Comment: No, it couldn't. It could explain losing the BIOS settings but the actual BIOS is not maintained by the battery.

Comment: I believe that it's the BIOS settings that failed, not the BIOS itself. Otherwise, how did he boot the PC enough to re-flash his BIOS?

Answer (score 0):

It could have been any of various reasons: device failure, HD failure, a latent bug in the older BIOS version etc.

And, Yes, sadly it can do it again. Just like any piece of code a BIOS is a program prone to small errors (hence the fixes and updates). Furthermore, devices get old and misbehave, or just reach strange edge cases.

I would run CHKDSK /f on my main HD, and update my video driver - just to be on the safe side.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen quite a few of these failures - Personally, I think they cut corners to cut the cost.

If it does it again any time soon, I would get your money back under warranty.